# sql convert ignores format?

Tags: sql-server-2005

running :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100)
```

will result :

```
Jan  4 2012  1:25PM
```

Ive been knowing this for years.

However  , yesterday, while I was driving , I thought to my self  :

> Hey! I gave him the format of 103 which is for datetime format ,
>
> But I didnt actually TOLD the convert that Im passing also a datetime
>   object ! ( e.g. getdate()))

So ive tried  :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 'lalala', 100)
```

And the result was :

```
lalala
```

so , now Im trying to convert 'lalala' to string  via datetime format (103).

which is ( by logic) should give me exception.

but it is not.

Any reasonable explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONVERT` takes into account both the target type and the expression's type to see whether the third argument should be considered. If you are converting a datetime to a string or the other way round, the third argument is considered. In your example, a string is converted to a string and so the third argument is ignored.

Consider this:

```
SELECT 1, CONVERT(datetime, '03/01/2011', 103)
SELECT 2, CONVERT(datetime, '03/01/2011', 101)
SELECT 3, CONVERT(varchar, '03/01/2011', 103)
SELECT 4, CONVERT(varchar, '03/01/2011', 101)
```

Here are the results:

```
--- -----------------------
1   2011-01-03 00:00:00.000

--- -----------------------
2   2011-03-01 00:00:00.000

--- ------------------------------
3   03/01/2011

--- ------------------------------
4   03/01/2011
```

As you can see, the last two ‘conversions’ didn't change anything, because both the source and the target type were `varchar`, even though the expression did look like a `date`/`datetime`.

Reference:

- [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [convert function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) only uses the 3rd parameter (`style`) if the 2nd one (`data_to_be_converted`) is `datetime`.

If it's already `varchar` it `returns` the value and don't make anything.

Comment: Interesting. So what happens if it's neither a varchar nor a datetime?

Comment: Actually, `CONVERT` [also considers the third parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx "CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)") when the expression is `float`, `real`, `money`, `smallmoney`, `xml` or `binary`/`varbinary`, but that is beyond the scope of either the question or an answer, probably.

Answer (score 0):

[The MSDN documentation for CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) says that the style parameter is interpreted based on the type of the value passed - so I guess it inspects the value and can tell which type it is.

For example, notice that a style of '1' means "mm/dd/yy" for datetimes and "Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation" for float values.